# How to get correct Row with FilterView?

Tags: google-apps-script

How can I get the correct cell that is selected in a `FilterView`?

if a `FilterView` is used, the Script can't get the real cell selected. Only the main data cell.

the code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var Value = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getCurrentCell().getValue()
  Logger.log(Value)
}
```

Without the filter view and selecting B4 it should show Clare, and with the filter view it should show Arne but it still show Clare.

[This is the FilterView problem](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TZEh2MAOpaZFAGOodWv5-J57xX_N5mN0Ws8v_PwqXbI/edit?usp=drive_web)

*(Filterview is sorted on the first column in an onther way then without filterview)*

Comment: The file you provided is not public. Can you make this publicly available?

Comment: Try https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F04vxLYCizmdoHzCzESDSodyZjpy_oAW1q_UMWDyGpU/edit#gid=0
have moved the doc to private email to be able to share freely.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. The spreadsheet you provided does not have a filter view added. How did you filter the data? What cell is currently selected?

Comment: fliterview Filter1 Not a filter for default view!
Selected B4 when running the script

Answer (score 1):

Filter views don't change the underlying data; they only change **your view** of the data.

`getActive` methods  (e.g. `getActiveRange()`, `getCurrentCell()`, `getActiveCell()`) are not affected by whatever filter views are opened, or which cell is selected there. You will notice that, when you change the selected cell in a filter view, the selected cell in the underlying sheet also changes, and that's the cell that's tracked by the `getActive` methods.

Therefore, you cannot retrieve the cell that's currently selected in a filter view.

#### File a Feature Request:

I'd suggest you to [file a Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113) in Issue Tracker if you'd like to see this functionality implemented (that is, programmatically retrieving whatever range is selected in an opened filter view).

#### Reference:

- [Filter data in a spreadsheet](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308952)